# View permissions of a Sharepoint site/page/list?

Tags: permissions

As a normal user how might I view the permissions of any given SharePoint site/page/document/list?

I need to contact the admin or manager of a section, and their name is not published in a document or page on the site. I'm thinking in the list of permissions the one with "Full Control" or closest to it will be the person I'm after. All I need is their active directory name or username.

Comment: if you are able to go to list permissions, you can use check permission button to view permission of any user, if you are saying that you need to display this to normal user who just have kind of read access, then it is not possible until you elevate from server side code...

Comment: @SiddharthVaghasia, yes the goal is to display to normal user who has read access.

Comment: You would have to give all your users (groups) the "Enumerate Permissions" permission, which by default only "Full Control" admins have. Only then can they check who belongs to groups (they themselves are not part of) or execute code that does the check.

Answer (score 0):

I found something that works well enough for the situation I'm in today, though it doesn't answer the question. A user with read only access can view the groups of a site by adding `_layouts/15/groups.aspx` to the url. Since some of our SP groups use the AD names it's a simple matter of feeding the names there into an active directory browsing tool to see the member names.

[image: People and Groups screenshot]

Presumably with higher level of read permissions a similar tactic using `/_layouts/15/people.aspx` would get the same results with less work. (For me that url shows "There are no items to show in this view of the "User Information List" list.")